# asp:menu Remove inline styles and div

Tags: asp.net

I have a have an asp:Menu and i am using css classes to format this menu.

```
<asp:Menu ID="MenuMain" runat="server" DataSourceID="SiteMapDataSource"   
   Orientation="Horizontal" RenderingMode="List" SkinID="None"  
   IncludeStyleBlock="false" StaticDisplayLevels="1">
<StaticMenuStyle CssClass="nav" /> 
<StaticSelectedStyle CssClass="active" />
<LevelSubMenuStyles>
  <asp:SubMenuStyle CssClass="level1" />
  <asp:SubMenuStyle CssClass="level2" />    
</LevelSubMenuStyles>
```

However asp.net dynamically adds the inline styles and divs that are generated by javascript associated to the menu.
Is there anyway to prevent this ?

Answer (score 0):

Add your own css class with different names and associate them with this in CssClass

```
<StaticMenuStyle CssClass="nav" /> 
<StaticSelectedStyle CssClass="active" />
<LevelSubMenuStyles>
<asp:SubMenuStyle CssClass="level1" />
<asp:SubMenuStyle CssClass="level2" />    
</LevelSubMenuStyles>
```

Hope it helps.
Don't forget to upvote it if it solves you problem.
Thanks.. :)